# ErrorException htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given ()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My controller

```
public function total_record()
{
    $tailor_measurement = DB::select('select count(*) from tailor_measurement ');
    return view('total record', ['tailor_measurement' => $tailor_measurement]);

}
```

My view total record

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Total Records</title>
</head>
<body>
@foreach($tailor_measurement as $row)
    {{$row}}
@endforeach
</body>
</html>
```

It give me error htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: C:\wamp64\www\shaban\resources\views\total record.blade.php)

Comment: `$row` is an object, so you can't display it directly within your template.

Comment: @Jeto than how I display?

Answer (score 2):

As you are trying to get the `count` of `tailor_measurement` this will return a number of rows an `integer` value not an array, if you `dd($tailor_measurement)` in your controller you will find it similar to this

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#1555 ▼
    +"count(*)": 35
  }
]
```

which is difficult to be accessed, you can do it much simpler like so

```
public function total_record()
{
   $counter = DB::table('tailor_measurement')->count();

   return view('total record', compact('counter'));
}
```

in your view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Total Records</title>
</head>
<body>
 {{ $counter }}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @tajamul hussain please mark this answer as accepted as long as it solve your problem, so the question will be considered as solved